# How to get the counts of indices when a pointer of array is passed to the calling function?

Tags: c

I want to eliminate duplicate values from an array. I am passing the values to a function by an array and after processing, collecting the returned array(processed data) by a pointer. The size of the pointer should be only the unique value present in the returned array. (It is working fine if I display there at the called function.) But in the calling function its showing lesser value when I return the array to the pointer in the calling function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int* test(int arr[],int size)
{
  int i,j;
  int flag=1;
  static int local_arr[10];
  int cnt=1;
  local_arr[0]=arr[0];

  for (i=1;i<=size; i++)
  {

     for(j=0;j<cnt;j++)
     {

     if(arr[i]==local_arr[j])
        {
         flag=0;
         break;
         }
         else
         flag=1;

     }
    if(flag==1)
    {
     local_arr[cnt]=arr[i];
     cnt++;
    }
    }

   return local_arr;
  }


int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    int *p,i;
    int arr[] = {1,2,5,7,4,2,4,7,9};
    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    p= test(arr,size);

    for(i=0;i<(sizeof(p)/sizeof(p[0]));i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",*(p+i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `sizeof(p)/sizeof(p[0])` is wrong.  You need a way to return the size as well as the data.  Also, the static array isn’t big enough for general use.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: the data is getting returned to the pointer but I am concerned about how to get the count of the actual data . If I replace ```sizeof(p)/sizeof(p[0])``` with 10 for example , it will show me the desired output as well as the garbage values of the remaining indices of the array/pointer.

Comment: You’ll probably need another pointer argument to the function that gets set to the number of values. Or you may be able to use a sentinel value (0, -1, INT_{MIN,MAX}, etc) to indicate the end.

Comment: `int* test(int arr[],size_t size, size_t *n)` and update the value at the location pointed to by `n` with the number of unique values before returning from `test()`. You also need to check that you do not exceed the bounds of `local_arr`.

Comment: The `i` loop runs up to `size`. So if `arr[]` has 10 elements `size` must be 9. You should write `for (i=1; i<size; i++)`

Comment: Thank you all for advising me I used David's said method which worked fine.